# Width of a cone

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry

Let $V=\{v_k\}$ be a collection of vectors of $\Bbb{R}^n$, and define their *cone* to be the set of all their non-negative linear combinations:
$$
C(V):=\Big\{ \sum_k a_k\,v_k; \; a_k\ge 0 \Big\}\;.
$$

Now, is there a standard measure of *width* for this cone? One I would have in mind is the following:
$$
W(C(V)) = \max \{ d(v_i,v_j); v_i,v_j\in V \}\;,
$$
where we take as distance (for example) the angle:
$$
d(v_i,v_j) = \arccos \dfrac{|v_i\cdot v_j|}{|v_i||v_j|}\;.
$$

Does anything similar to this already exist? Maybe realized in a completely different way?
Any reference would also be welcome.